# Join in .NET Core query inside for

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, mysql-connector

I need to join 2 tables in the database to get two values ​​from the second.

But I must do it within the for statement.

How could I do it?

```
foreach (AvgValues avgValues in db.AvgValues
    .Where(avg => (firstDate == null) || (avg.Timestamp > DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    .Where(avg => (secondDate == null) || (avg.Timestamp < DateTime.ParseExact(secondDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is defference by doing that in or outside the for statement?
This is not a join at all, it's more like a between...

Comment: This is an X/Y problem, you're asking a question about your solution rather than your actual problem. Please state the actual issue so we can gain a better context and point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your comments and sorry for my bad expression. i am new in dotnet. I want to add a join with another table **Channels** where avgValues.channel == channels.channel ((.Join(avg => db.Channels in Channels.channel == Avg.channel)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my solution has been get out the query from the for statement:

```
var q =
    from a in db.AvgValues
    join c in db.Channels on a.Channel equals c.Channel 
    select new { AvgValues = a, Channels = c };

foreach (var x in q
    .Where(avg => (firstDate == null) || (avg.AvgValues.Timestamp > DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    .Where(avg => (secondDate == null) || (avg.AvgValues.Timestamp < DateTime.ParseExact(secondDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
    {
        ...
    }
```